# Need exctra last word in first line form below input

Tags: python, python-3.x, strip

I need output for below input data using python 2.7

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please copy the code to your question in a [code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). If the link of that image ever changes, the value of your question disappears.

Comment: i have added script in image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
import re
your_string = "reth10.890"
number = re.findall("\d+\.\d+", your_string)
requested_string = re.sub(number[0], '', a)
print(requested_string)
>>>'reth'
```

If your string contains more floats you have to select the last one in number